# Efficiently determine whether two arbitrarily-sized integers share a digit

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

My current algorithm creates two new integers initialized to 0 (one for each input), then sets the *n*<sup>th</sup> bit to 1 if the integer's corresponding input contains the digit *n*. The bitwise **AND** of these integers is then 0 if the inputs don't share a digit.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to make this function more efficient. Is there something I'm missing? Example implementation (in Java) below.

```
boolean shareDigits(long a, long b)
{
    int aBits=0, bBits=0;
    if(a==0) aBits=1;
    if(b==0) bBits=1;
    while(a!=0)
    {
        aBits |= (1 << (a % 10));
        a/=10;
    }
    while(b!=0)
    {
        bBits |= (1 << (b % 10));
        b/=10;
    }
    return (aBits & bBits) > 0;
}
```

Comment: In your while loop you have two divisions. Divisions are slower than other operations. There is way to rewrite your code using one division one multiplication and one substraction. I am going to leave that as an exercise to you. Also note that the compiler probably will optimise it.

Comment: `pretty sure there's a way to make this function more efficient` - as always. Don't bother unless you "felt" efficiency lacking. Here, you could have an array of `int`s containing `1<<0` to `1<<9` to be indexed by "the `%10s`(*may* help - re-measure!), an early out (using a `do…while (0 == a&b)`-loop. Going overboard (`arbitrarily-sized` - `BigInteger`?), use a `char[]` comfortably fitting into, say, 2nd level cache and do several digits at a time.

Answer (score 1):

### Edge cases

You don't handle negative integers very well. Specifically, the modulo operator, when performed on a negative integer with a positive divisor, may return a negative value. And when this negative value is something like, say, `-2`, then you get `1 << -2`, which results in setting a high bit instead of the bits for 0-9.

### Duplication

You currently have duplicated the code for `a` and `b`. By making use of smaller methods, you can get rid of the duplication:

```
int getBitsFor(long num) 
{
    int bits=0;
    if(num==0) bits=1;
    while(num!=0)
    {
        bits |= (1 << (num % 10));
        num/=10;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

And then use like so:

```
boolean shareDigits(long a, long b)
{
    return (getBitsFor(a) & getBitsFor(b)) > 0;
}
```

### Readability

It would help if you were to put spaces between operators and the operands. Basically, I find `int aBits = 0` more readable than `int aBits=0`. The less effort I have to spend on interpreting the code, the more effort I can spend actually writing or improving the code.

For reference:

```
int getBitsFor(long num) 
{
    int bits = 0;
    if(num == 0) bits = 1;
    while(num != 0)
    {
        bits |= (1 << (num % 10));
        num /= 10;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Compare with the snippet above, see which feels easier to read for you.

### Simplification

200_success pointed this out, but they deleted their answer (although I found that it made a good point):

If you wrote do-while loops instead, then you would not need the special case for num == 0:

```
int getBitsFor(long num) 
{
    int bits = 0;
    do
    {
        bits |= (1 << (num % 10));
        num /= 10;
    } while (num != 0)
    return bits;
}
```

### Performance

You want to know if there's a faster way check if integers share a digit.

To be honest, I don't know. Your implementation looks pretty fast. But your implementation also takes a constant amount of calculations related to the size of the input and makes no use of shortcuts.

One shortcut that I can come up with - if a number contains all the digits, then you don't need to continue.

But perhaps checking for this case makes the worst case slower again...

I also checked https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html which is a collection of "Bit Twiddling Hacks", but there doesn't seem to be an algorithm for checking for duplicated digits in there.